# Which table stores the foreign key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

This is possibly a really simple question that I need clarified.

If I have 2 tables, say User and Activity.  There is a 1 to Many Relationship from User to Activity (A User can have many activities).

Which table should have the foreign key?

Comment: The `activity` table. Otherwise you would have to add multiple columns for possible activities to the `user` table like `activity1`, `activity2`...

Comment: @juergend I was wondering..why don't you write it as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought

Comment: @AlexGreg: I don't feel like going into it more in detail and this comment is hardly an answer

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:

- A table containing FK can have **multiple** rows containing the same value in their FK field(s). FK references a key but is not *itself* a key, so you can have duplicates there.
- A table *referenced* by the FK can have (at most) **one** row that corresponds to the same FK value in the other table. The reason: FK references a *key*, which forbids duplicates.

So, assuming "1" side is User and "many" is Activity, the Activity should contain the FK.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key ensures, that for each row there is a corresponding value in the referenced table. So to determine if there needs to be a foreign key and where, ask yourself following questions:

> Can there be a user without an activity?

If the answer is no, then you have to create a FK in user table referencing activity table.

> Can there be an activity without a user?

If the answer is yes, don't create a FK constraint.

If the answer is no, you probably have a m:n relationship (unless an activity can only have one user), as multiple users can have the same activity and each activity can have multiple users. Then you need a table which resolves this m:n relationship inbetween.

```
user_table             user_activity_table        activity_table
id | more_columns      user_id | activity_id      activity_id | more_columns
```

Then `user_table` references `user_activity_table` and `activity_table` references also just `user_activity_table`. `user_activity_table` only has those 2 columns.